# How to retrieve data from promise object in React JS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to get data from an API. But the fetch result is returned as promise object. I want to return the contents from this promise to invoke react action.

```
let loginData = fetch(loginURL, { method : 'POST', headers : headerParams, 
 body: bodyParams })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    return data['retrieve-agent'];
});
console.log('loginData ===>', loginData.agent);
return {
  type: 'GET_AGENT_DETAILS',
  payload: loginData
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of `async-await` to get the result without using a promise or else you would need to resolve the promise from the function

```
async fetchFunction() {

    let loginData = await fetch(loginURL, { method : 'POST', headers : headerParams, 
     body: bodyParams })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        return data['retrieve-agent'];
    });
    console.log('loginData ===>', loginData.agent);
    return {
      type: 'GET_AGENT_DETAILS',
      payload: loginData
    }

}
```